# Connect other process GUI

Tags: c#, user-interface, process

Is there a way to get access over other processes (for example Windows Calculator) and retrieve information that can help perform GUI operations (emulate 1 + 1 = ... operations)? What API should be used? Are there any solutions for C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [Spy+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460725.aspx) tool, which is available with Visual Studio setup.
This is a must tool to investigate *native* windows application.

The main attributes of it are:

- get properties of any window
- sniff `WM_...` messages applications, be able to filter them and see the main paramaters (LPARAM, WPARAM) values.

Comment: As I understand it is a graphical tool.And I need low api access above running process.

Comment: In order to be able to *use* it you just need to run it, it has UI. POint to a window of interest and read properties or messages you are interested in. If application you are listening to is a *native* application or build in C#, if that app does not provide some communication bridge (IPC mechanism for example) known to you, there is no other way then communicating to it via WindowsSDK `SendMessage`, trying to simulate the real OS event.